# Django ModelForm ignores the data supplied via form and saves the superuser name in the table

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm new at using Django forms (Django altogether), and on my first form, I have encountered this error. No matter what data I post via the form it saves the superuser name in all the fields.

Here are the files,

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

class NewCustomer(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('name', 'mobile_number', 'email', 'address')
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.
def customers(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render(request, "customers.html", {'customers': customers, 'custactive': "active"})

def customer_details(request, pk):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "customer_details.html", {'customer': customer})

def new_customer(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewCustomer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.save(commit=False)
            customer.name = request.user
            customer.mobile_number = request.user
            customer.email = request.user
            customer.address = request.user
            customer.save()
            return redirect ('customers')

    else:
        form = NewCustomer()

    return render(request, "new_customer.html", {'form': form})
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with the code? Understandably I need to save new data that I supply with the form.

Really appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to tell the form which fields to get from `User` object.
Now if you have extended the `User` model and have `name`, `mobile_number`, `address` specified, you need to modify your code.

```
def new_customer(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NewCustomer(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        customer = form.save(commit=False)
        customer.name = request.user.name
        customer.mobile_number = request.user.mobile_number
        customer.email = request.user.email
        customer.address = request.user.address
        customer.save()
        return redirect ('customers')
```

The reason whz superuser's name is saved in all fields is because all models have their **str** method, which tells python what to print out if object itself is used.